# Discord.py Bot react to every message in a specific channel with json?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want that my bot in a channel (which was set earlier) react to every single message!

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_reaction_add(message):
        with open('vorschlag channel.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            guilds_dict = json.load(f)
        channel_id = guilds_dict[str(guild.id)]
        await client.get_channel(int(channel_id)).react('✅')
```

I think that the code is probably completely wrong, could someone help me here?

Comment: Do you want this just for one server?

Comment: @Dominik No, I want every server to be able to choose the suggested channel itself. I've already done that with a json file, but somehow I can't get the bot to add a reaction to every message that was sent in this channel

Comment: Then use an „on_message“ event in order to react to every message.

Comment: @Dominik I don't think that's what max meant, pretty sure they wanted to react to every message that has been sent, once something happens.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate through the messages in the channel:

```
async for message in client.get_channel(int(channel_id)).history(): #Loop through all messages
    message.add_reaction("✅") #Add Reaction for every message
```

But don't just copy and paste this code, there are a few weird things in your code... One of which is the fact that the variable "member" doesn't exist (at least not visible in the code you sent), but you are trying to access it.

And one last thing: you should probably put the error that shows up when you execute the code inside of your question, to make life easier for the people answering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the event `on_reaction_add` is fired when a reaction is added. Since you want to react to every message that is sent, you should use `on_message`:

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        with open('vorschlag channel.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            guilds_dict = json.load(f)
        if str(message.guild.id) in list(guilds_dict.values()): #do this to prevent KeyError
            channel_id = guilds_dict[str(message.guild.id)]
            await client.get_channel(int(channel_id)).react('✅')
```

Comment: When I start the code I get this error:

channel_id = guilds_dict[str(guild.id)]
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined

Comment: Oh yeah, it should be `message.guild.id`, fixed it now